# List dynamic dependencies of a Windows executable in command prompt?

Tags: windows, dll, dependencies, mingw, windows-10

I'm using MinGW on Windows 10 to build Windows executables (programmed in Rust, though I don't think that part matters). I don't like having to manually keep track of which of the libraries I use have DLL files that need to be included with the release builds of my applications, so I'd like to be able to write a script that can automatically find and copy them next to the app after I build it. To that end, I'm trying to find a command-line program that will list (to stdout or a file) the DLL dependencies of a Windows executable I pass it - bonus points if it filters out DLLs that I can assume are included with Windows in the first place.

I know about Dependency Walker already, but it's old and doesn't seem to like Windows 10 very much (it yields a lot of false negatives); I know about dumpbin, but from the sound of it I can't use that outside of a Visual Studio context anyway. Cygwin apparently has a working ldd, but I'd rather not install Cygwin in its entirety just for this one purpose if I can help it.

Are there any other tools available for this purpose? If not, how could I program one myself? I've seen a script that scrapes the output of `objdump -p` (a MinGW utility) for this purpose; I can always fall back on that if there's no better way.

Comment: I think you are looking at part of it, backwards. Rather than static libraries requiring dll's (which i guess technically is correct) a more cononical approach is to view your executable as relying on external assemblies located in a dynamic link library. Depending on how you created those assemblies (dll's) you require the static library for each dll to use the dll. If you access the dll's implicitly (you link to the static library accompanying the dll) then it is linked at load time. If you used the `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()` you don't require static libraries with the dll.

Comment: In the later case you only require the dll. In the former you will require the static libraries as well, and the program will crash if they aren't there. Alternatively you can link to dll's in at compile time which effectively uses them as static libraries(I beleive by __forceinline which forces inline in vs). If this is done you obv no longer need the dll's at run time. Dll's are primarily used in an application so that parts can be changed and updated without replacing (rebuilding) the whole project. The user can quickly update as opposed to reinstalling.

Comment: https://github.com/mpreisler/mingw-bundledlls

Comment: Open wsl and do `strings my.exe | rg dll | less`

Answer (score 1):

I interpret you question as follows. Given a `.exe` how can I write a program which lists the external dependencies to dynamic link libraries? Given this list how can I sort for dll's which aren't included with windows?

You have to work out how the dynamic linker in windows get's this information. See the `.exe` or portable executable file format, specifically the Import table.

> "PE File Imports Earlier, I described how function calls to outside
>   DLLs don't call the DLL directly. Instead, the CALL instruction goes
>   to a JMP DWORD PTR [XXXXXXXX] instruction somewhere in the
>   executable's .text section (or .icode section if you're using Borland
>   C++). The address that the JMP instruction looks up and transfers
>   control to is the real target address. The PE file's .idata section
>   contains the information necessary for the loader to determine the
>   addresses of the target functions and patch them into the executable
>   image. The .idata section (or import table, as I prefer to call it)
>   begins with an array of IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTORs. There is one
>   IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR for each DLL that the PE file implicitly links
>   to. There's no field indicating the number of structures in this
>   array. Instead, the last element of the array is indicated by an
>   IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR that has fields filled with NULLs. The format
>   of an IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR is shown in Figure 10."
>
> "- Matt Pietrek March 1994 Matt Pietrek is the author of Windows
>   Internals (Addison-Wesley, 1993). He works at Nu-Mega Technologies
>   Inc., and can be reached via CompuServe: 71774,362 This article is
>   reproduced from the March 1994 issue of Microsoft Systems Journal.
>   Copyright © 1994 by Miller Freeman, Inc. All rights are reserved. No
>   part of this article may be reproduced in any fashion (except in brief
>   quotations used in critical articles and reviews) without the prior
>   consent of Miller Freeman." - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx

The `.exe` should have an import table which a structure defined in WINNT.H containing a `DWORD name` for each implicitly linked dll. Note you will have to see how Windows 10 has changed and if there are changes to the executable format. Hope this helps if you wanted to program something to do this.

Also obtaining a list of windows standard user mode driver's and dll's should be easy to find and check against.

Snippet of `.exe` I wrote in c++, I can find

> _CxxThrowException  w _CorExeMain **mscoree.dll**
>   8                               !  0  1 
>   2  3  9  :  ;  <    )  *  +  ,  -  .  /  4  5  6  7
>   "  #  $  %  &  '  (  =  >  ?  N  O  R  T  V  P  Q  S
>   U  @  B  C  D  E  G  H  I  J  K  M  A  F  L  Y  Z  \
>   [  ]  ^  _  `  a  b  c  d  e     f  ÿÿÿÿ   ±¿DNæ@»
>   Ès@     .?AVbad_alloc@std@@ Ès@     .?AVexception@std@@ Ès@
>   .?AVbad_array_new_length@std@@  Ès@     .?AVtype_info@@

So it appears searching for string `".dll"` would work, then filter it with a list of windows standard dll.

Alternatively I have written a very very crude forms application which minimally does what you ask. It's on github both the source and the executable. I'm don't work with forms applications so forgive the bugs. https://github.com/marshalcraft/CheapoDllDependencyTool

Comment: Also to use my cheapo dll dependency tool, simply hover over file in top left and click open. An open file diologue box will appear, choose the file and click ok. I noticed that compared to dependency walker in at least one application (I wrote) which uses ws2_32.dll  (a windows socket dll), Dependency walker does not detect it, however my application does.